# Find one index for each common numpy arrays in two lists using numpy

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to find index of each common elements (here numpy arrays with various dimensions) between two separate lists, corresponding to one of them which will be called **master** in this question. The other list will be called **slave** which its elements are checked only and their indices are not important. The testing lists are as:

```
import numpy as np
slave = [np.array([1,5,7,1]), np.array([7,3,5,7]), np.array([1,2,3,8]), np.array([1,2,3,8])]  # or a = np.array([np.array([1,5,7,1]), np.array([7,3,5,7]), np.array([1,2,3,8]), np.array([1,2,3,8])])
master = [np.array([1,5,3,7]), np.array([1,5,7,1]), np.array([1,2,3,8]), np.array([7,3,5,7]), np.array([3,2,5,7]), np.array([1,2,3,8]), np.array([1,2,3,8])]
```

**The result** of the aforementioned code must shows **master**'s indices 1, 2, 3, and 5.

***Problem specifications:***
**1.** I have used `b = np.delete(master, np.where(np.array(list(map(np.array(slave).tolist().__contains__, map(list, master))))), axis=0))` to delete common elements from **master**, but this command line removes all occurrences of `np.array([1,2,3,8])` from **master** (i.e. **master**'s indices 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6), which is not the aim; Only two of them must be deleted (because **slave** contains only two of them) so the result must be as `[[1 5 3 7] [3 2 5 7] [1 2 3 8]]`. This problem is more obvious if removing `[np.array([])]*3` from `[np.array([])]*7` where the length of the result will be 0.
**2.** It must be considered if an element in **slave** is repeated e.g. we have two `np.array([1,2,3,8])` in **slave**, the result must shows two different indices of **master**; i.e. in this example it must shows **master**'s indices 1, 2, 3, and 5 and not 1, 2, and 3. How to do so when we have non-1d numpy arrays.

**Using numpy is of interest**, not looping.
Besides, I would be appreciated if let me know if there is a comprehensive way using numpy to reach the goal, if numpy arrays inside the lists have various shapes.

Comment: The 'fast' numpy code uses compiled methods working on a 'whole' multidimensional array, things like `np.sum` with `axis`.  This moves the loops to compiled code.  Lists containing arrays are still lists.  The fact that they contain arrays instead of numbers or other lists doesn't matter, in fact in some ways it makes them harder to work with.  All the more so if the lists/arrays vary in size.  And don't be fooled by object dtype arrays - like lists they contain references to objects, not compact data that compiled code works with.

Comment: Your question given input and output described is not clear to me

Comment: Thanks @pippo1980 for your contribution. The explanation is edited and more clarified now.

Comment: I would rephrase your question changing ‘same element’ with something in the line of ‘closer element’ otherwise your question won’t be clear to the readers

Comment: The term 'closer element' would take the readers away from the goal of the question, as I think. However, I have tried to clarify more the question considering your comment.